# ClickThrough on Google Webmaster Tool and Traffic Source in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm new to SEO and website management, but eager to learn. I manage a newly revamped site and I'm tracking it on Google Analytics and in Google Webmaster tools.
The Webmaster tools show that I get about 3200 impressions and 180 click through's a week. Google Analytics show that no traffic comes from search engins, all of the traffic is direct. On average, I get about 60-80 visitors a day, shouldn't Google Analytics show at least a few of those visitors as having come from the search engines?.

What does that discrepancy mean? I can't seem to wrap my mind around it...

Thank you in advance,
Svetlana

Comment: It will help if you paste the google analytics code your using on the pages. That might lead to a clue. It's possible to have impressions without traffic from search engines, but I'm not sure the click through's part makes any sense.

Comment: I agree the click through part confuses me as well. I'm using the standard code, provided in the Analytics setup. Here it is:`<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16852855-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>`

Comment: Looking in Analytics do you have any data under the key word reports? and if so does Google show up as a source?

Comment: Hi Matthew, no analytics is not showing anything for keywords at all, but webmasters tool does. What is funny that another site I track on Analytics, has the same code installed but it shows google as the traffic source and also shows the keywords that brought people over.

Comment: just out of interest are you using adwords / adsense or something simlar to drive traffic to the site?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'm not using adwords/adsense on either of the sites.

Comment: when you same "same" code is it exactly the same? is the UA code different?

Comment: Matthew, when I say "same" I mean everything in the code is the same, except for the "UA"...

Comment: Does any one have any suggestions? Any comments would be greatly appreciated. I am still at a loss as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible scenario.

- Google Webmaster Tools tracks searches and clicks TO your domain
- Google Analytics records page views and keywords ON your domain
- So between leaving Google and reaching your pages with the GA tag, the keywords are getting stripped

Things to check:

- Analytics is correctly configured on **every** page - make sure the tracking tag in use on the homepage is that same as the internal pages
- You might have JavaScript redirects that are stripping out the referrer and keyword information - browse your site with JS disabled and see if everything behaves properly
- You might have meta-refreshes that are redirecting visitors and losing the referrer info. [Disable meta-refreshes](http://www.jkwebtalks.com/2010/02/disable-automatic-meta-refreshredirect.html) and try browsing the site.
- You might have some server-side redirects that strip the referrer information - use a tool like redbot.org to see what headers are being returned when you request your site

---

**Update:** here's my generic simple .htaccess. I've modified it for your case to redirect to Home.html. Let me know if it works.

**Update 2:** I've added in the redirect to www. based on Paul Irish's [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), which has the most comprehensive .htaccess I know:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs - especially not with and
# without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause SEO problems (duplicate content).
# That's why you should choose one of the alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated. Remember: Shorter URLs are sexier.
# no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you rather want to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
# and uncomment option 2.
# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 2:
# To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
# Be aware that the following rule might not be a good idea if you
# use "real" subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to Home.html
RewriteRule .* Home.html [PT]
```

Note: you'll have to rename or delete the existing index.html for this to work.

Comment: thanks for your reply! The scenario you gave makes sense. Now as far as checking things: Analytics cide us the same on every page - it is copy/pasted straight from the settings page in my analytics profile. I do have Java applets running on the site and some features are not functioning with Java blocked (i.e. the blog summary, photo gallery) - would that matter? I used redbot.org and I'm not really sure what I'm looking at... LIke I mentioned, I'm new to this :) But looks like everything came back green.I get a flag "The Content-Length header is correct" is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: Does any one have any suggestions? Any comments would be greatly appreciated. I am still at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: Hi @Svetlana, can you post the URL of your site?

Comment: Hi @ciarian, here is the URL: http://criscyborg.com/

Comment: Your homepage, criscyborg.com, is doing a meta-refresh, which redirects visitors to criscyborg.com/home.html. This is killing the referrer information.

Set up a 301 redirect from the home page to home.html and you will be fine.

You can see the problem if you do a view-source on the home page:- in Chrome, view the following URL: view-source:http://criscyborg.com/

Comment: Hi @Clarian, I created the .htaccess file with this content: "redirect 301 /criscyborg.com http://criscyborg.com/Home.html" The site loads fine but I do not think it's working as far as the referrer info goes. Did I misunderstand your recommendations? Should I reverse the links and have it be "redirect 301 /criscyborg.com/Home.html http://criscyborg.com"

Comment: I think the htaccess line you want is "redirect 301 / /Home.htm"

Comment: Hi @Clarian, I tried that redirect line and got this error message:This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage athttp://criscyborg.com/Home.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmHome.htmhas resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: Hi @Svetlana, not sure why you got a redirect loop, but it might have been because of the typo in my comment above. See my updated answer which has a full htaccess for your situation.

Comment: Hi @Clarian, thank you so much for your help with the code, I am not getting any errors on load now. But it seems like it hasn't fixed the issue with the traffic source info being erased, I am showing 100% direct traffic today, after having updated the .htaccess file last night... Any thoughts?

Comment: Hah, I was being an idiot - you have to rename the existing index.html for the .htaccess rules to work. Rename it to _index.html and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @Clarian, thanks for the tip! I'll try it tonight! One more thing though, it looks like my www redirect broke with all these updates. Google can't seem to find any links that point directly to criscyborg.com and is only able to locate www.criscyborg.com. Is there anything I can add to the code you posted to cure this?

Comment: Just to clarify, I would like to use the non-www as my primary address. Can I add this sequence after your code:  Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^criscyborg.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.criscyborg.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: @Svetlana, updated my answer. But the index.html is still in place - did the htaccess work as intended?

Comment: @Clarian, thank you so much for helping me troubleshoot this! Let me try it out tonight, and I'll post an update afterwards :D

Comment: Hi @Clarian, I updated the .htaccess file and also renamed the index file and it looks like the www redirect is working fine, but I'm still showing 100% direct traffic... ugh... any ideas why? Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: I still see the index.html file in place. You have to remove it for me to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I guess I renamed the file in my published folder and forgot to delete the original file on the server :) Duh!!!

Comment: I think I've got a problem now, I am getting a 403 forbidden error when I go to www.criscyborg.com. How come? I noticed it after I deleted the index file! I renamed the file back index.html and deleted the .htaccess but I was still not getting the redirect to criscyborg.com/home. I had to revert it back to original configuration and only then it was fixed.... Why does it have to be so difficult?

Comment: I think you need to do some testing to see if you mod_rewrite is working? Maybe you can ask technical support at your host? http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask them, but I doubt they'll be able to help. They were the first resource I tried using when I first noticed this issue, all they advised was to set up a 301 redirect. As far as testing goes, is there a way to do it so the site does not become dysfunctional while I'm playing around?